# How are the constants in hydraulics calculated?

Tags: physical-constants

I would like to know (out of sheer morbid curiosity) how constants in hydraulics are calculated.  The constants are, for good ol' 'Merican units; 63025, 5252,and 231.  These constants came out of "Introduction to Fluid Power."  The constant 231 is how many cubic inches are in one gallon.

The equation for input HP is HP = (T * N)/63025.  Why is '63025' used?  Does that make sense?  Basically I'd like to know where these units came from? I'm not sure if I explained my question better.  I believe one of the responses I got pretty much hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Could you please specify what are these constants and where have you seen them?

Answer (score 1):

231 = number of cubic inches in 1 U.S. gallon (by definition)

5252 = 33,000 ft-lbs / 2 * pi --> for the formula HP = Torque * RPM / 5252, where Torque is measured in foot-lbs

The conversion becomes 63025 instead of 5252 when Torque is measured in inch-pounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsepower